Confusion regarding manuscript status in IOP's article tracking system, the status of awaiting IOP staff decision made me very confused
In the ScholarOne Manuscript System, the status changed from "Awaiting Decision" to "Awaiting IOP Staff Decision". Do you know why the state changes from awaiting decision to awaiting IOP staff decision? In my previous submission, I received the referee's report shortly after the awaiting decision status. The status of awaiting IOP staff decision made me very confused.
